# Ionic <ion-scroll>/<ion-content> scrolls further than screenlength

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

Here is a demonstration of what is going wrong: [Video](https://2.sendvid.com/a4ktyh30.mp4)

The pane scrolls too far, it should stop after the last button but it seems to scroll for exactly another page-height.
I have multiple ion-contents but I hide the ones that I don't use at that moment with ng-class="ng-hide"

```
<body>
<!-- Five number code -->
            <div class="animated fadeInRight" data-ng-class="numberCodeShow">
            <ion-content scroll="false" style="position:static;" scrollbar-y="false">
                <div id="splash">
                    <p class="logo">
                    <span class="leftUpColors" data-ng-style="{'background-color': style.style1}"></span><span class="leftDownColors" data-ng-style="{'background-color': style.style2}"></span><img  class="homeimage" data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{style.logo}}"></p>
                </div> 
                <form data-ng-submit="showDashboard(code.fiveNumberCode)">
                    <ul class="fieldList padding">
                        <li><p style="text-align: center; padding-top: 10px;">Log in met de 5-cijferige code</p></li>
                        <li class="loginCodeWrapper">
                            <div class="input">
                                <input class="loginCode" data-ng-model="code.fiveNumberCode" type="tel" name="code" maxlength="5" required/>
                            </div>
                        </li>   
                    </ul>
                        <div class="padding">
                          <button data-ng-style="{'border-bottom-color': style.style1}" style="background-color: #FFFFFF"  type="submit" class="button button-block button-default signinbutton">Sign In<i data-ng-style="{'color': style.style1}"class="icon ion-arrow-right-c signinIcon"></i></button>
                        </div>
                </form>
                </ion-content>
            </div>
            <!--// Five number code //-->

            <!-- Dashboard -->
            <div class="animated fadeInLeft dashboard" data-ng-class="dashboardShow">
                <ion-content scroll='true' style="position:static;" scrollbar-y="false">    
                    <div id="splash">
                        <p class="logo">
                        <span class="leftUpColors" data-ng-style="{'background-color': style.style1}"></span><span class="leftDownColors" data-ng-style="{'background-color': style.style2}"></span><img class="homeimage" data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{style.logo}}"></p>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="details">                                   
                        <p class="welcomeName" data-ng-style="{'border-bottom-color': style.style1}"><i data-ng-style="{'color': style.style1}" style="padding-right: 5px;" class="fa fa-user"></i>Welkom {{user.name}}</p>
                        <label data-ng-style="{'border-bottom-color': style.style2, 'color': 'black'}">Accordering</label>
                        <div>
                            <div class="padding">
                                <button data-ng-click="showOpenDocuments()" data-ng-style="{'border-bottom-color': style.style1}" style="margin: 0; background-color: #FFFFFF" class="button button-block button-default"><i data-ng-style="{'color': style.style1}"class="icon ion-android-folder-open buttonIconLeft"></i>Mijn openstaande taken</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="padding">
                                <button data-ng-click="showAllDocuments()" data-ng-style="{'border-bottom-color': style.style1}" style="margin: 0; background-color: #FFFFFF" class="button button-block button-default"><i data-ng-style="{'color': style.style1}"class="icon ion-android-folder buttonIconLeft"></i>Alle Documenten</button>
                            </div>
                            <label data-ng-style="{'border-bottom-color': style.style2, 'color': 'black'}">Overige</label>
                                <div class="padding">
                                    <button data-ng-click="getOrganisations()" data-ng-style="{'border-bottom-color': style.style1}" style="margin: 0; background-color: #FFFFFF" class="button button-block button-default"><i data-ng-style="{'color': style.style1}"class="icon ion-android-contacts buttonIconLeft"></i>Contactpersonen</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="padding">
                                    <button data-ng-click="showImageUpload()" data-ng-style="{'border-bottom-color': style.style1}" style="margin: 0; background-color: #FFFFFF" class="button button-block button-default"><i data-ng-style="{'color': style.style1}"class="icon ion-camera buttonIconLeft"></i>Foto Uploaden</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="padding">
                                    <button data-ng-click="backToFolders()" data-ng-style="{'border-bottom-color': style.style1}" style="margin: 0; background-color: #FFFFFF" class="button button-block button-default"><i data-ng-style="{'color': style.style1}"class="icon ion-document-text buttonIconLeft"></i>Bestanden</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="padding">   
                                    <button data-ng-click="showNotifications()" data-ng-style="{'border-bottom-color': style.style1}" style="margin: 0; background-color: #FFFFFF" class="button button-block button-default"><i data-ng-style="{'color': style.style1}"class="icon ion-android-notifications buttonIconLeft"></i>Notificaties</button>                         
                                </div>  
                        </div>                      
                    </div>
                </ion-content>  
            </div>

            <!--// Dashboard //-->
```

This is a piece of the code so you can see how I build it up. The variables that are in the code are either `ng-show` or `ng-hide`. In this case `numberCodeShow = 'ng-hide'` and `dashboardShow = 'ng-show'`.

I tried setting `max-height` on ion-scroll but it doesn't work. Does anyone know why this problem occurs?

Comment: Can you replicate the behavior in a plunker or codepen? That'll make it easier for us to isolate the exact problem and suggest a solution.

Comment: Seems I have fixed it myself by putting scroll = false on the and make a seperate underneath with height:100vh;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I have fixed it myself by putting scroll = false on the  and make a seperate  underneath with height:100vh;

To answer A. Vin's question:

This looks like what I had:

```
<ion-content scroll=true>
.....
.....
.....
</ion-content>
```

This resulted in the scroll going to far because of an upper div.

This fixed the problem:

```
<ion-content scroll=false>
<ion-scroll style="height:100vh">
...
...
...
</ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

I hope this resolves your issue too!
If you have any other questions feel free to ask :)

Comment: Jelmer, can you please elaborate on this answer, I have the same issue and would love to know how you fixed it.  Thanks.